# Date time Conversion in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I know this will be a silly question, but I tried everything and still couldn't achieve what I wanted to do.

**This is my question:**

I want to check two time values and a date, I have string which is having time like this "05.30 AM". 
I want to convert it into time format [it is better if i can convert exactly the way it is now].
I know there is a way which can compare two time values using:

`NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];`.

I have followed below code to convert my string value to the time format but it is only returns null.

Please guide me for this issue:

```
NSString* tim = @"11:12 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSDate *formatedTime= [formatter dateFromString:tim];
NSLog(@"TIME : %@",formatedTime);
```

Comment: hi darsan first of all you have to convert tim to date format

Comment: Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298010/ios-converting-time-and-date-to-user-time-zone

Comment: yeah that is what i want to do in the first place..for that im using above code..but it is returns null

Comment: yes darshana check the link provided by subhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case (with `tim` formatted the way you have it) you just missing one line: `[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];` this will tell `formatter` not to look for `date` in your string.

```
NSString* tim = @"11:12 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *formatedTime= [formatter dateFromString:tim];
NSLog(@"TIME : %@",formatedTime);
```

Comment: i tried your answer sir.. but still i get value like this.2000-01-01 05:12:00 +0000

Comment: if formatter will not look for the date.. then why i still get an date for my out put..and why my time is incorrect? i cant understand sir

Answer (score 0):

You need set the format.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: thank you.. now i got some value.. but the time is wrong...i pass 11:12 AM.. but it returns 2000-01-01 05:12:00 +0000.. how can i fix this

Comment: I think this is because the date doesnt hold time zone, try to set it. `[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];`

Comment: you were right sir..now i can get output like this....2000-01-01 11:12:00 +0000.. but still i have a problem..how can we check this is AM or PM...?

Comment: You can control this when printing the date, i think it is 24 hours date, try to set another formatter for printing the date, [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* tim = @"11:12 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];

NSDate *formatedTime= [formatter dateFromString:tim];
NSLog(@"TIME : %@",formatedTime);
```

But you will receive

> TIME : 1999-12-31 23:12:00 +0000

since year is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to format your String like this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
[formatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 25 Jan 2014 5:30:22 +0000"];
```